# File template for Azure Storage acount in ADF

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I have a file named Incremental-b659b42f-49ec-4b0a-95d9-50001bd2af34.csv created in Azure Storage container. This name is always changed, as it is the pipeline ID.

How can I create a template so that in the Copy Data task the Incremental-*.csv file is taken and its contents are copied to the Snowflake table?
[image]

Or how can I make it so that the file is always replaced by another one, so that there is always only one file in the folder

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that your file in storage will be generated as `Incremental-<pipeline run id>.csv`. It means you are using a pipeline to generate it which is executing by trigger.

**If it's same pipeline or different pipeline**, get its latest pipeline run id from [Pipeline Runs - Query By Factory - REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/query-by-factory?view=rest-datafactory-2018-06-01&tabs=HTTP)  list **by using its name**. Use this `runId` and build your filename and use that in the copy activity filename.

First use a web activity to get the pipeline runs list of your pipeline. Use the below URL and body with `POST`.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<ResourceGRP_name>/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/<Datafactory_name>/queryPipelineRuns?api-version=2018-06-01
```

**Body:**

```
{
    lastUpdatedAfter: "@{adddays(utcnow(),-20)}",
    lastUpdatedBefore: "@{adddays(utcnow(),1)}",
        "filters":[
    {"operand":"Status","operator":"In","values":["Succeeded"]},
    {"operand":"PipelineName","operator":"In","values":["<your_pipeline_name>"]}
]
}
```

Here, you need give your pipeline name and change the dates as per your requirement.

[image]

Next, to build the required filename, use the below expression which gets last runId (latest runId) from the pipeline runs array.

```
Incremental-@{activity('Web1').output.value[add(length(activity('Web1').output.value),-1)].runId}.csv
```

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

On every pipeline run, it gets the latest pipeline runId and builds the required filename. You can use in your copy activity source filename as per your requirement.